# How to extend a line passing through two points until it intersects the x-axis {or y-axis}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I draw a line passing through two points (A) and (B), in my case its (0.1,40) and (1,0), and extending that line until it intersects the x-axis of the plot on a log-scale?

Is there a way to calculate that point on the x-axis? Below is my MWE, the blue line stops at (1,0) as I don't know yet how to proceed from there.

If the line extends to the y-axis? In some cases this line could extend until the y-axis on the right side, instead of the x-axis, if I scale the plot shorter.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}    
% For drawing block diagrams, plotting, etc
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, quotes, backgrounds, intersections, fit}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}   

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Frame Title}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{height=7.0cm, width=6.0cm,compat=newest}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={\scriptsize Pole at the origin },
    xmin=0.1, xmax=100,
    ymin= -60, ymax=60,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,0.5)},anchor=south},
    xlabel={\scriptsize $\omega$ (radians)},
    ylabel={\scriptsize mag (dB)},
    y tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    xmode=log,
    grid = both,
    % modify tick labels
    xtick = {0.1,1,10,100},
    xticklabels={0.1, 1, 10, 100},
    tick style={draw=none},
    ytick = {60, 40, 20, 0, -20},
    yticklabels={60, 40, 20, 0, -20},
    ]
    \coordinate (O);
    \draw[blue, thick] (0.1,20) -- (100,-40);
    \draw[blue, thick] (0.1,40) -- (1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please upload a code which can be compiled to reproduce the problem

Comment: Apologies for the errors, I have edited the code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Completely unrelated comment: `\scriptsize` and other size changing macros are not macros that take an argument, they are switches, so you should do `{\tiny text}` if you want to limit the effect, try e.g. `{\tiny text} not tiny text \tiny{tiny text} also tiny text` to see this. (In this case you don't need the braces at all though, and personally I'd add `font=\scriptstyle` to `x`/`y label style` and `title style` instead.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I think this solves the problem, using intersection  \draw (1,0) to (intersection of 0.1,40--1,0 and 0.1,-60--100,-60);

Comment: You can also just make the line plenty long - it will be clipped by the plotting area: `\draw[blue, thick, shorten >=-100] (0.1,40) -- (1,0);`

Answer (score 1):

By extending the line and using the intersection with the x-axis coordinates, this solves the problem. Specifically the line

```
\draw (1,0) to (intersection of 0.1,40--1,0 and 0.1,-60--100,-60);
```

Comment: That's the ticket. If I were you, I would replace `0.1,-60` with `{xticklabel* cs:0}` and `100,-60` with `{xtickabel* cs:1}`. These are (axis) coordinate-free ways to refer to the lower-left and lower-right corners of the axis plot. That way if you change `xmin`, `ymin`, or `ymax`, you don't have to update that line.

Comment: Also: I would name `nodes` at the coordinates for extra readability and portability, as in: `\draw[blue, thick] (0.1,40) node[coordinate] (A) {}-- (1,0) node[coordinate] (B) {};` Then the continuation is `\draw[red] (B) to (intersection of A--B and {xticklabel* cs:0}--{xticklabel* cs:1});` This way everything only depends on the coordinates of the two points determining the line, and you don't have to retype them.

Comment: I think `node[coordinate] (A) {}` is the same as `coordinate (A)`. I do not think that I have seen `coordinate` as an option to a node before.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang Thanks for the suggestions. I will try that to clean up the code a bit.